# Rename tabs to one cell from another in the same Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, tabs, rename

I'd like to have a google script, where:
1-Tab name changes are applied to A1 to A15 from Sheet1
2-Values are cells from B1 to B15 from the same Sheet1

I currently have this script that works perfectly, but the changes are required directly from cells A1 to A15, so the purpose of what I want, it don't work:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var aba = planilha.getActiveSheet();
  var celula = e.range;
  var linha = celula.getRow();
  var coluna = celula.getColumn();
  if (coluna == 1) {
    var nome = celula.getValue();
    if (nome != "") {
      var abas = planilha.getSheets();
      abas[linha].setName(nome);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify what you are missing? If I understand correctly you want to limit changes to cells in Column A from row 1 to row 15, but currently are only checking for column 1. There are a few ways to approach that. Either add another `if` to check for the row as well or use `getA1Notation()` and then use a regex compare to figure out if it meets the criteria

Answer (score 0):

To rename tabs to the names in `Sheet1!B1:B` when `Sheet1!A1:A` is modified, try this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. '
      + 'See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.'
    );
  }
  renameTabs_(e);
}


/**
* Renames tabs to a name in Sheet1!B1:B15 when Sheet1!B1:B15 is manually edited.
* Cell B1 corresponds to the second sheet, cell B2 to the third sheet, and so on.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function renameTabs_(e) {
  if (!e.value
    || e.range.columnStart !== 1
    || e.range.rowStart > 15
    || !e.range.getSheet().getName().match(/^(Sheet1)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  const sheetName = e.range.offset(0, 1).getDisplayValue();
  if (sheetName) {
    e.source.getSheets()[e.range.rowStart]
      .setName(sheetName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this approach you can change all of the sheets names from `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = e.source.getSheets();
  if (sh.getName() == shts[0].getName() && e.range.columnStart == 1) {
    e.source.toast('Gate1')
    if (e.value) {
      shts[e.range.rowStart - 1].setName(e.value);
    }
  }
}
```

Please note this only works for user edits.  It will not work if column one is changed via formula or another script.